# Joining Shapes and fill - Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Wanted to check if there is a way to achieve (b) by joining dots (a) in Inkscape.

[image]

Comment: Can't you draw the lines over the T shape with the dots, then delete the original? There's nothing that can do this automatically in Inkscape as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is always trivial, but you can try something like the following:

- Select the shape and Path > Break apart (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>).
- Select the horizontal part and duplicate it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.
- Select the vertical part and duplicate it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.
- Combine the horizontal part: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and select: **Extensions** > **Render** > **Frame** and press Apply.
- Repeat that for the vertical part.
- Ungroup the results and align the rectangle shapes as shown below, then **Path** > **Union**.

[image]

- To be able to fill the shape, select it then **Path** >  **Stroke to path** and break apart <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>
- Ungroup the result, and remove the bottom shape. Select the remaining shape and choose: **Path** > **Stroke to Path** then break apart  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

[image]

---

<sub>The animation was divided to two parts to be able to upload it (2MB limit).</sub>

Comment: Can you add some instructions too? Just in case the video link rots. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Nice answer

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. You are awesome. :)